# Upload image using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to upload image in the following code. But when I upload image  I got an error message  undefined index: image
The error  message :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: image

Filename: controllers/home.php

Line Number: 86

Backtrace:

File: C:\softwares\xamp\htdocs\ASOFT\Projects\CG_Pack\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 86
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\softwares\xamp\htdocs\ASOFT\Projects\CG_Pack\index.php
Line: 293
Function: include_once
```

**Controller**

```
public function view()
    {
        $data=$this->data;
        $data['error']= '' ;
        $this->load->view('display',$data);
          $path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $imgext=strtolower(strrchr($path,'.'));
        $imgname= $this->generateRandomString().$imgext; 
       if($path!='')
       {  
       $im= $this->config->item('base_url').'/uploads'.'/'.$imgname;
       $x=$this->do_upload($imgname);
 $data['img']=$im;


 if ($x['error']=='')
   {
   $this->user_model->getimage($data['img']);

   }
   else
   {
    $data['error']=  $x['error'] ;
    $this->load->view('display',$data);
   }
   }
    }


 function generateRandomString()
  {
     $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
     $randomString = '';
     for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
         $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
     }
     return $randomString;
  } 

        function do_upload($img)
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1024 ';  
        $config['file_name'] = $img;   
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))

        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $data['error']=$error;
            return $data;

        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
         $data['error']='';
             return $data;
        }
        return;
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public function getimage($data)
    {
        $var=array('img'=>$data);
        $this->db->insert('login',$var);
        $query = $this->db->get('login');   
        return $query;
    }
```

**View:**

```
<?php
if($error!='') { ?>
<script>
//print_r($error['error']);
//alert('<?php echo $error['error']?>');
alert('Please upload less than 1 mb file');
</script>
<?php }?>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Add Image</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2>Upload image</h2>
          <form action="<?=site_url('home/view')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
          <input type="file"  class="upload" name="image" id="file" required value="<?php echo set_value('image'); ?>" />
          <!-- <input type="submit" name="btn-reg" value="Upload" /> -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
                       $(document).on('change','.upload',function(){
      files = this.files;
      size = files[0].size;
      //max size 50kb => 50*1000

      if( size > 1000141){
         alert('Please upload less than 1mb file');
         return false;
      }
      return true;
});
</script>    


           <div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">Choose your div</button>
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">div 1</a></li>
  <li class="disabled"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">div 2</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">div 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
     <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
          </form>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

Here  I  listed the controller, view and model.  When I  upload image  I got the error message undefined index. In the view  input field is also image, but I got the error message. Please provide solution for this.

Comment: Are you uploading file in modal popup?

Comment: yes i want to upload file in modal popup